# Input type="date" resets when I try to write the last value React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, state, react-hooks

This is the way I set up my state with React Hooks:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({Actual_Arrival, otherValues});
const { Actual_Arrival } = values;
```

I have the handleChange function:

```
  const handleChange = name => event => {
    const value = name === 'photo' ? event.target.files[0] : event.target.value;
    formData.set(name, value)

    setValues({...values, [name]:value})
  }
```

And this is my input element of type date, which works with the date picker but not when typing the date manually

```
<input  
    placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"
    onChange={handleChange('Actual_Arrival')}
    type="date"
    className="form-control"
    value={Actual_Arrival} />
```

And then the value of the date is submitted to the backend when I click the button inside of the form, but I don't like the behavior of the input box reseting when ever I use the text input and not the date picker.

EDIT:

This worked for my specific case, the value still locks, when choosing the date but the input itself doesn't lock so it's editable after the lock.

I changed a conditional that I had in my input value that was causing the lock, now it doesn't and makes the editing better. Here is my current input element:

```
          {
            // Actual_Pickup == '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' &&

         (
          <input
            placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"
            onChange={handleChange('Actual_Pickup')}
            type="date"
            className="form-control"
            value={Actual_Pickup} />
          )

          }

          { Actual_Pickup != '1900-01-01T00:00:00.000Z' &&

            <h6 className="current-val">Current Value: {formatDate(Actual_Pickup)}</h6>
          }
```

Comment: Did you mean `handleChange('Actual_Arrival')`?

Comment: Yes, I edited as it should, I do have it with quotes on my code.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?  I am having the same problem.

Comment: The value still resets but the form doesn't lock, I'm going to edit the solution.